# Intent for "Settings > Connected Devices > Connection Preferences" page

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nfc, android-settings

I'd like to know the `Intent` for the [`AdvancedConnectedDeviceDashboardFragment`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/connecteddevice/AdvancedConnectedDeviceDashboardFragment.java). On API 28 this page can be reached through: `Settings` > `Connected Devices` > `Connection Preferences`.

> This fragment contains all the advanced connection preferences(i.e, Bluetooth, NFC, USB..)

The logcat of the manual interaction:

```
D/SettingsActivity: Switching to fragment com.android.settings.connecteddevice.AdvancedConnectedDeviceDashboardFragment
D/SubSettings: Launching fragment com.android.settings.connecteddevice.AdvancedConnectedDeviceDashboardFragment
```

Launching it through `SubSettings` doesn't work:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.SubSettings");
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Because it is not set `exported="true"` it gives me:

> .SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.SubSettings (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{75bbdbc 11970:com.acme.application.debug/u0a460} (pid=11970, uid=10460) not exported from uid 1000

Is there a chance to start it through the parent `SettingsActivity` with `Intent` extras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While browsing `com.android.settings.Settings` I've found the name of the `SettingsActivity`:

```
ConnectedDeviceDashboardActivity extends SettingsActivity
AdvancedConnectedDeviceActivity extends SettingsActivity
```

And so I've wrote a simple wrapper method, which still `throws`:

```
public void showSettings(@NonNull String activityName) throws ActivityNotFoundException {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$" + activityName);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

It can be used alike this:

```
try {
    showSettings("AdvancedConnectedDeviceActivity");
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

See [`Settings.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/Settings.java) for further `SettingsActivity` names to use.